# how to find total sum of last k terms for every index i in range l to r?

Tags: algorithm, fenwick-tree

how to find the total sum of last k terms for every index i in range l to r in an array of n size for q queries using Fenwick tree and k is different for every query.It's a problem on hackerearth [hacker with team](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/fenwick-binary-indexed-trees/practice-problems/algorithm/hacker-with-hack-function-03dd9bc0/description/)
i have its tutorial but i don't get it how they have done because no explanation has been given.
could anoney please explain how it is done?

Comment: do u know fenwick tree at the first place?

Comment: i know about fenwick tree, but i am not able to figure out how it is implemented in this case.